# Display an edit text box on click of a button

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am creating a user form in android. I want to display an edit text box on click of a button. below that button, while simultaneously the contents originally present below that button to move more down. 
How can this be done?

Comment: just add your view in layout using addViewAt(index,yourEditText);

Comment: @HirenDabhi:But how does it know which layout to add the adit text in? Where should that be mentioned in the code?

Comment: post your layout or screen shot of your screen.

Comment: it depends on your requirement. suppose button(is at the top) and some other controls are added in linear layout and you want to add edittext in this layout then use addViewAt(1,youredittextcontrol).

Comment: @HirenDabhi: RelativeLayout l1=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(r.id.asd)    l1.addView(temp,16). temp is the edit text box. but there is no change in the layout. Can you please answer in the answers section?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you just want to "display an edit text box on click of a button" why don't you just..

**Keep the EditText in your XML layout** file for that activity **below the Button** where you want it..

**XML set it's**

`android:visibility = "gone"`

and making instance of that

`EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.thatEditText);`

in activity...in your button click event set

`et.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Answer (score 3):

Define the view in your layout, then in code, show and hide it with
`myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` and `myView.setVisibility(View.GONE)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
    //xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btn"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:text="Button"
    />
<EditText 
   android:id="@+id/edtbox"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    


    />
</LinearLayout>


//Activity

//oncreate

editText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

btn..setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Define your EditText in your xml and hide it. On button click, change its visibility to View.Visible.

```
 YourEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
     {
        public void onClick(View v)
         {              
          YourEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }
       });
```

Answer (score 1):

If your layout is relative then addView(yourView, index) doesn't work. Suppose you want to add view after some other control and reference to that control.

e.g.

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/templayout">
   <Button android:id="@+id/button"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="add"/>
```

and you want to add edit text control after text View then on button click :

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.templayout);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.title);
    EditText yourEditText = new EditText(this);
    relativeLayout.addView(yourEditText, params);
```